# IIFE in $(document).ready not work as expected

Tags: jquery, iife

I know this might be a dumb question, but i spent quite some time and still cannot figure it out.

For sake of brevity, i created a simple demo:

```js
$(function() {
  alert('hi, jQuery!')
  
  (function() {
    console.log('hi, IIFE')
  })()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The `alert` work as expected, but `console.log` failed. More strangely, the error message logs:

`Uncaught TypeError: alert(...) is not a function`

Why did this even happen, as the `alert` statement was already executed?

## Update

This question is due to lacking knowledge of how JS `auto semicolon insertion`(a.k.a ASI) works.

Refer [JavaScript Semicolon Insertion - Everything you need to know](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) for more detail.

Comment: You missed `;` on the line `alert('hi, jQuery!');`

Comment: @Quentin Roger it seems fixed this demo, but should js runtime engine support leaving out `;`?

Comment: @Xlee it does support it, but you need to understand what happens when you do. The error message is stating that the return of `alert(...)` is not a function (and it of course isn't.)

Comment: Remove the spaces after the alert() and you'll see:  `alert()();` - `alert() is not a function`  (it's not `alert is not a function`)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978883/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-semicolon-before-an-iife

Comment: For example, if you removed the `()` from around the iife and preceeded it with an operator, such as `+` or `!`, your code would work sans semi-colon https://jsfiddle.net/7rv3k617/. but that's nonsensical, just use a semi-colon.

Comment: @Kevin, great thanks for detailed explanation, i get the basics wrong.

Comment: Your code is basically `var foo = alert("bar"); foo("world");` with the semicolon missing. Hence why it is important to use semicolons.